# How can one get the XPATH from the 'x' and 'y' coordinates using Appium in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, appium, coordinates

Is there any possible way to get the `xpath` for a mobile app given just the `x` and `y` coordinates for the element using Appium and Python?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it cannot be done in Appium in general way. And there is no such keyword to do this.

But you can do this yourself as the following.

1- Get the page source

> `page_src = driver.page_source`

2- Get the all elements coordinate attribute in a dictionary or list

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as el_tree

page_src = driver.page_source
element_coords={}
page_src_xml = el_tree.fromstring(page_src)
for element in page_src_xml.iter():
   element_bounds = element.attrib['bounds']
   coords = {}

# calculate center of elements (which is x,y of element)

   bounds = element_bounds.replace('[', '').replace(']', ',').split(',')
   coords.update({'x': (float(bounds[0]) + float(bounds[2])) / 2})
   coords.update({'y': (float(bounds[1]) + float(bounds[3])) / 2})

# coords is what you need for next steps
```

3- Try to compare the **coords** (from step 2) with your desired, in a for or while loop.

4 - when you find the element with the desired coords, you simply can return the element and act on it.

5 - Here you don't need to get XPATH for doing something on element, because you already locate it.

But if you need the element xpath for further usage, I'm afraid you can get the XPATH from element, but the other option like "text" or "content-desc" maybe available.

Hope this helps